# How to place images on own page that stays with text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to insert an image (any size < 1 page) in a word document that is on its own page, centered, with caption underneath. The main text before and after this page should be continuous, and completely fill up the page that it resides on (e.g., no blank spaces), sort of like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkZKM.png), but instead of a table it is a image. In terms of anchors, I want this page/image to stay with the text, as I plan on adding more text before and after, but it doesn't have to be exactly where I insert it. Is this possible with word 2013?

I have tried inserting section breaks but the text on the preceding page doesn't fill the full page.

Comment: This microsoft answer might be useful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/how-to-keep-image-in-same-place-on-its-own-page/8b0fdbee-1280-44a8-8170-35d831793d90?db=5

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can probably get it is to make sure the image stays on a page of its own. You can do this by right clicking on the image and selecting `Wrap Text` -> `More Layout Options`. Set the wrapping to `Top and Bottom` and try playing around with the options under `Distance from text`.

I would suggest adding a large value like 22 for `Top` distance to the image and doing the same for `Bottom` to the caption. As I said, text won't flow around it but it will make sure the image and caption stay on a page of its own.

Comment: The image is not always the same dimensions of the page, and I don't want to stretch the image. This also will not work with a lengthy caption.

Comment: @Moop, I have updated my answer.